# Spring + Hibernate + Repository + JPQL: Почему запрос выполняется с ошибкой?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, repository

Имеется сущность Фильм:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "films")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Film implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8647833898589302685L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id_film", nullable = false)
    private int idFilm;

    @Column(name = "alternative_name", length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String alternativeName;

    @Column(name = "original_name", length = 60, nullable = true)
    private String originalName;

    @Column(name = "year", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "SMALLINT(4)")
    private short year;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "film_genre", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "film_id", referencedColumnName = "id_film"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", referencedColumnName = "id_genre"))
    protected Set<Genre> genres;

    protected Film() {}

    // get/set
}
```

И сущность Жанр:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "genres")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"idGenre", "films"})
public class Genre implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2549525646752215530L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id_genre", nullable = false)
    private int idGenre;

    @Column(name = "genre_ru", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String genreRu;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Set<Film> films = new HashSet<>();

    protected Genre() {}

    // get/set
}
```

Между сущностями связь Многие-ко-Многим!

К сущности Фильм имеется репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface FilmRepository extends JpaRepository<Film, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT new Film(f.idFilm, f.alternativeName, f.year) FROM Film f")
    Page<Film> findFilms(Pageable page);

    @Query("SELECT new Film(f.idFilm, f.genres) FROM Film f JOIN f.genres WHERE f.idFilm = :id")
    Film findFilmGenres(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

Метод `findFilms()` абсолютно рабочий! При вызове метода `findFilmGenres()` возникает ошибка. Ее содержимое:

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_1_0_ from films film0_ inner join film_genre genres1_ on film0_.id_film=g' at line 1
```

Подскажите в чем синтаксическая ошибка SQL-запроса? И как его написать правильно, чтоб возвращаемый объект (сущность) `Film` имел только `idFilm` и список `genres` остальные поля должны быть `null`?

Comment: Вы включите все логи, в хибернейте show_sql. И в логах увидите запрос, попробуйте его выполнить руками и посмотрите в чем ошибка.

Comment: Включил, вот запрос: `Hibernate: select film0_.id_film as col_0_0_, . as col_1_0_ from films film0_ inner join film_genre genres1_ on film0_.id_film=genres1_.film_id inner join genres genre2_ on genres1_.genre_id=genre2_.id_genre inner join film_genre genres3_ on film0_.id_film=genres3_.film_id inner join genres genre4_ on genres3_.genre_id=genre4_.id_genre where film0_.id_film=?` как и пишет в сообщении к ошибке, где-то здесь неверно: `. as col_1_0_ from films film0_`, но как исправить?

Comment: Вы пробовали руками этот запрос выполнить? Вам что СУБД говорит? И вы в вопрос добавьте эти данные.

Comment: СУБД возвращает тот же ответ с ошибкой, что и выше: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_1_0_ from films film0_ inner join film_genre genres1_ on film0_.id_film=g' at line 1 `

Comment: Как написать такой `SELECT film_genre.film_id, genres.genre_ru FROM genres, film_genre WHERE genres.id_genre = film_genre.genre_id AND film_genre.film_id = ?` на JPQL?